# Instancia de servidor restuful no tomcat

Tags: java, apache, postgresql, tomcat, restful

Pessoal desenvolvi um aplicativo - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=br.com.apprioconcurso

Estou utilizando um servidor restfull conexão com o banco postgree em hibernate.

Esse servidor esta hospedado no bitname em um tomcat, porém algumas vezes por algum motivo ele cai e é necessário reiniciar o servidor manualmente, existe algum outro jeito de fazer isso? Eu preciso ter dois servidores caso um caia eu chamo o outro? como funciona esse processo final para deixar meu servidor sempre startado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se possuir acesso ao cron de sua nuvem, uma forma muito comum de fazer o que você quer é usar um script [Watchdog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchdog_timer).

Ele consiste em ficar checando de tempo em tempo se um serviço ou programa está em execução e caso negativo executa um comando de inicialização.

Para isso se faz uso do agendador (em Linux é o Cron) com um intervalo de tempo aceitável que o sistema a ser monitorado fique fora. Geralmente usa-se o tempo médio que o serviço leva para "parar + iniciar".

Abaixo um script exemplo que serve para muitos serviços.

Basicamente você indica ao script qual serviço monitorar, qual o comando para iniciar o serviço, endereços de e-mail para alertas e caminhos para alguns binários

Supondo que salve o script no seu $HOME com o nome de watchdog.sh, , dê permissão de execução com `chmod +x $HOME/watchdog.sh"`, edite sua crontable com `contrab -e`
e adicione uma linha como essa

```
*/5 * * * *  $HOME/watchdog.sh
```

Indicando que será verificado a cada 5 minutos

Segue um script de Watchdog

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME=tomcat
START=`which $NAME`
STARTCMD="$START + _ARGUMENTOS_"
NOTIFY=EMAIL1
NOTIFYCC=EMAIL2
GREP=`which grep`
PS=`which ps`
NOP=`which true`
DATE=`which date`
MAIL=`which mail` # ou sendmail dependendo da distro
RM=`which rm`

# $PS -ax|$GREP -v grep|$GREP $NAME >/dev/null 2>&1 # Caso tenha problema com serviço que roda com um usuario que roda muitos serviços
$PS -efx|$GREP -v grep|$GREP $NAME >/dev/null 2>&1
case "$?" in
   0)
   # Em execução, não fazer nada.
   $NOP
   ;;
   1)
   echo "$NAME NÃO ESTÁ EM EXECUÇÃO. INICIANDO $NAME E ENVIANDO AVISOS."
   $STARTCMD 2>&1 >/dev/null &
   mkdir -p "$HOME/tmp"
   NOTICE="$HOME/tmp/watchdog.txt"
   echo "$NAME não estava executando e foi iniciado em `$DATE`" > $NOTICE
   $MAIL -n -s "Aviso Watchdog" -c $NOTIFYCC $NOTIFY < $NOTICE
   $RM -f $NOTICE
   ;;
esac

exit
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o Nagios para monitorar seu servidor, e com alguns parâmetros reiniciar seu servidor de forma automatizada. Mas recomendo que você investigue seu servidor e tente achar algum padrão para você configurar uma monitoração mais assertiva no Nagios.

Segue um ponto de partida:

[Nagios tutorial Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nagios-4-and-monitor-your-servers-on-ubuntu-14-04)